# How do I modify this script to start looking for a match at Row 16?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet set up like a form.  In Sheet1!B2 I have the value to add/search for.  In Sheet1!B3, I have comments to add/replace.  The accompanying script searches for a anywhere in Sheet1!A1:A on another spreadsheet and replaces the second column with the new values if a match is found. If no match is found, it adds the newly added values to the bottom of the first column. Here is the script:

```
function myFunction() {
  
   var lock = LockService.getDocumentLock();
  lock.waitLock(20000);
  // DO SOMETHING
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  lock.releaseLock();
  
  // source spreadsheets
  var sourceSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var srcSheet = sourceSpreadSheet.getSheets()[0];

  //destination spreadsheet
  var destinationSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SheetID');
  var destSheet = destinationSpreadSheet.getSheets()[0]; 

  var values = srcSheet.getRange("B2:B3").getValues().reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.concat(b)
});
var partNum = values[0];
var row;
destSheet.getDataRange().getValues().forEach(function(r, i) {
    if (r[0] === partNum) {
        row = i + 1
    }
})
row = row ? row : destSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
var data = destSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 2).getValues()[0].map(function (el, ind){
  return el = values[ind] ? values[ind] : el;
  })

var statusValue = srcSheet.getRange("B2:B3").getValue();   //added

if (statusValue != '') {                       //added
destSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 2).setValues([data]);   //added

srcSheet.getRange("B2:B3").clearContent()
}
}
```

The script functions well and I use it for many projects.  However, I am wondering how do I modify this script so that the search begins at Sheet1!A16 of the other spreadsheet?  I have need of putting some values in the top 15 rows that will match the values being searched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var lock = LockService.getDocumentLock();
  lock.waitLock(20000);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  lock.releaseLock();
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssh = sss.getSheets()[0];
  var dss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SheetID');
  var dsh = dss.getSheets()[0];
  var values = ssh.getRange("B2:B3").getValues().flat();
  var partNum = values[0];
  var row;
  dsh.getRange(16,1,dsh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().forEach(function (r, i) {
    if (r[0] === partNum) {
      row = i + 16;
    }
  })
  row = row ? row : dsh.getLastRow() + 1;
  var data = dsh.getRange(row, 1, 1, 2).getValues()[0].map(function (el, ind) {
    return el = values[ind] ? values[ind] : el;
  })
  var statusValue = ssh.getRange("B2:B3").getValue();   //added
  if (statusValue != '') {                       //added
    dsh.getRange(row, 1, 1, 2).setValues([data]);   //added
    ssh.getRange("B2:B3").clearContent()
  }
}
```